# jQuery - after several AJAX page loads the ID selectors fails

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

here's the thing - I load partial pages via AJAX. I use the external jQuery plugin - http://2.s3.envato.com/files/53574557/index.html in my partial page.

Everytime the images are different. Let's say I load that partial page for 10 times. For example, after e.g. 3th page load and so on, I see the same images, but in the page HTML code they're different. It's like they're cached after some time.

The whole situation is an example, because I see that if I use any other external plugins, or even if I use the ID selectors (`$('#someID')`) in my partial pages, after some time that selectors don't fire. It's a new situation for me.

The only dirty-come-around of that problem is to add some dynamic generated string, e.g GUID to the ID `$('#someID32a13c24-d1ee-49db-afb1-5f7e5e094046')` and then everytime everything is fine. But to be honest - it could make a total mess in my code, and I believe that there is some other come around of that problem. Any ideas ?

Here's a very simple ajax call code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '...',
   cache: false,
   complete: function(result){}
});
```

Comment: Can you check without the GUID, but clearing the browser cache manually before every load? This is so weird.

Comment: Is your server using [pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/using)?

Comment: @Tony Its hard to say without seeing a full example ajax requests code.  Would you mind updating your question with one and while you're at it, are you seeing this behavior in all browsers?